# How to change "SOLD" message on quick view and product details

Tags: virtuemart

I need to change the "SOLD" message to "CALL US" on quick view and product details, but I'm not able to find the correct .php file I need to edit.

Joomla: 2.5
Virtuemart: 2.6

The theme has custom files for virtuemart too. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Did you try download all files in your computer and find the word "sold" ? Probably is a .ini language file.

Comment: We searched all .ini files, there was one "DR_SOLD="SOLD" string but didn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It was an .ini file like you said but not on .../templates/OUR_TEMPLATE/..., not even in "components" folder

It was in a folder "languages" in the root of the Joomla install. Thanks again Max.